# Whileloop condition not triggering

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
OrcHealth = 15

while ((OrcHealth <=0)) or ((Action != 0)):
    if Action == 1:
        HeroAttack=random.randint(1,5)
        OrcHealth = OrcHealth - HeroAttack
        print("You see an opening, this is your chance! You swing your blade and do",HeroAttack,"to the orc.\n This brings the beast down to", OrcHealth)
        Action = int(input("You grip your sword tightly and think about what to do next.")
else:
      print("The battle is over.")
```

Hello, I have a project due for school and I can't seem to get the result I need. This is part of a larger program, but what I am having a problem with is the whileloop recognizing that it should end when OrcHealth is equal to or less than 0. The other condition, ((Action != 0)) works just fine.

I can strike it as many times, but OrcHealth will display for example, -11, without the whileloop terminating. Have I written my condition wrong or missed something?

Comment: You want `>= 0` instead of `<= 0` in your condition

Answer (score 1):

Using `or` means that if *either* condition is `True` then your loop will continue. Consider using `break` to jump out of the loop if your `OrcHealth` falls below `0`. Something like this:

```
while action != 0:
    if action == 1:
        heroAttack = random.randint(1,5)
        orcHealth = orcHealth - heroAttack
        if orcHealth <= 0:
            break  # this will end the loop
        print("You see an opening, this is your chance! You swing your blade and do",heroAttack,"to the orc.\n This brings the beast down to", orcHealth)
        action = int(input("You grip your sword tightly and think about what to do next.")
else:
      print("The battle is over.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your logic for the while loop. It should state

```
while ((OrcHealth > 0)) or ((Action != 0)):
```

because you actually do want the loop to continue while the "Orc" is alive, not dead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `or` with an `and`, and check that the orc health is greater than 0.

The loop wasn't exiting because, for one, if the Orc "died", the first condition was continuously met. But even if you fixed that, as long as one continues to type "1", the 2nd condition is met. Since `or` checks if either condition is met, you'd always get a true result. So what you really want is to ensure that all of these are true:

1. Orc is alive.
2. The last action was non-exiting.

Only then should we re-prompt for an attack. You can meet this criteria by `and`ing them together.